"なくしものをした" How to understand it?
そういった彼の瞳を僕はしってる。これはなくしものをした人の瞳だ
In this sentence the narrator explains, I suppose, that the eyes of the other person are those of someone who knows loss.  but I'm curious, what does なくしものをした mean grammar wise?
if なくしもの is "loss thing"  how to read をした here? Made something lost?
